# Export keystore from jenkins credentials manager

Tags: jenkins, keystore, credentials

is there any way to export a prior uploaded keystore from the jenkins plugin manager?
I have uploaded a .p12 file which is used for signing I would like to download on my new laptop. Unfortunately I am on the road with no access to my backups, so I hope there is an easy solution to just get the file from the jenkins credentials manager.

It is shown as KeyStoreUploadedBytes in credentials.xml.
I know that there is a way to descrypt password stores there via the /script section. Would that also be possible for the keystore and receive it as byte array for example?

Best
Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Find the ID of you certificate (e.g. in the URL):

[image: Credentials ID in URL]

Execute a script in scripting console of your Jenkins instance:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import hudson.security.*
import java.security.*
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

def creds =  CredentialsMatchers
                .firstOrNull(
                        CredentialsProvider
                            .lookupCredentials(
                                Credentials.class,
                                Jenkins.getActiveInstance(),
                                ACL.SYSTEM,
                                Collections.emptyList()
                            ),
                        CredentialsMatchers.withId("9X9X99XX-XX9X-9X99-9X9X-9X9X9999XXX9")
                )

// This will print a decrypted password
def password = creds.password
println password

// This will print all the available aliases
creds.keyStore.aliases().each { println it }

// Imagine, the alias you need is myapp.
// Get JVM representation of you certificate and key
def cert = creds.keyStore.getEntry("myapp", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray())).certificate
def privKey = creds.keyStore.getEntry("myapp", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray())).privateKey

// Format certificate and key
certpem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cert.encoded) +
        "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
keypem  = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
        DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(privKey.encoded) +
        "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

// Print them
println certpem
println keypem
```

BTW, `cert.encoded` and `privKey.encoded` will contain the bytes you need, but, I guess, you're more interested in human-readable certificate / key representation.